# xslt Date Formatting and converting back to DateTime - BusinessWorks

Tags: xml, datetime, xslt, xpath, businessworks

I am trying to format a dateTime to remove the milliseconds part and just have seconds (e.g. 2015-04-07T17:13:19Z)

The issue is that when i use the dateTime function in XSLT as xpath in the BW Designer i need to convert the output string back into a dateTime. BW does not support functions in the editor or EXSLT.

The xsl: element executionDateTime:
current()/ns4:tradeHeader/ns4:partyTradeInformation[1]/ns4:executionDateTime

@executionDateTimeScheme element current()/ns4:tradeHeader/ns4:partyTradeInformation[1]/ns4:executionDateTime/@executionDateTimeScheme

Please help if you can

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me what you try to achieve. Do you need help to remove the milliseconds from a datetime serialization, or rather to parse a datetime?

Comment: I need to remove the milliseconds from the datetime - the xpath for picking the element up : current()/ns4:tradeHeader/ns4:partyTradeInformation[1]/ns4:executionDateTime - i need to take this elements value and take milliseconds out

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is a UTC datetime in the form of:

```
<input>2015-05-19T10:04:56.123Z</input>
```

you can use the expression:

```
concat(substring-before(input, '.'), 'Z')
```

to remove the milliseconds component and receive:

```
2015-05-19T10:04:56Z
```

Comment: The issue i have with this though is its attached to a scheme so original code was: current()/ns4:tradeHeader/ns4:partyTradeInformation[1]/ns4:executionDateTime, but also current()/ns4:tradeHeader/ns4:partyTradeInformation[1]/ns4:executionDateTime/@executionDateTimeScheme for the scheme attribute. When i replace the top line with above it also populates the scheme. It shouldn't do so. Please advise

Comment: @VincenzoFranco I am not sure what you mean. Obviously, you need to replace `input` with the XPath to your node. -- P.S. Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead. This would have been much simpler if you had posted a small example of your XML, along with the expected output (as code) to begin with - see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: replaced now what i mean is the above xpath in my question checks to see if there is executiondatetimescheme and then populates if in message. This way its always populated with the datetime that is in the element. I dont want it to do this.

Comment: @VincenzoFranco Sorry, I have no idea what you mean. Please review the link above and post a **reproducible** example.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
tib:parse-dateTime('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', translate(<<insertYourString>>, 'TZ', ' '))
```

input: string(2015-04-07T17:13:19Z)

output: dateTime